# how to check condition in "for" loop based on dropdownlist selected value in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Based on count number selected from Dropdown list, i have to generate table rows dynamically. For example, if count is 3, then 3 table rows has to be generated (Each table row have 4 table data). Please can anyone help me to implement this scenario?

Here is View code:

```
<table id="dynamiccount">
    <tr> 
        <td>
            <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.Label("please select count")
                </div>
            </td> 
            <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.count,@ViewBag.dynamic as SelectList,"select")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.count)
                </div>

            </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<table id="dynamic">

    <tr> 
        <td> 
                <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.value1)
                </div>
        </td>
        <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                     @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.value1, @ViewBag.Value1 as SelectList, "select")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.value1)
                </div>
            </td>
            <td> 
                    <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.value2)
                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.value2, @ViewBag.Value2 as SelectList, "select")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.value2)
                    </div>  
        </td>
            <td>
                <div class="editor-field">
                    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.value3, @ViewBag.Value3 as SelectList, "select")
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.value3)
                </div>
            </td>
    </tr>


     </table>
```

Now, based on model.count value selected from dropdownlist, i need to generate table rows accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a simple FOR:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= countDropDown; i++)
{
    //Add one Row with its data
}
```

As you didn't provide your code... the answer is super generic.

**UPDATE:**

Selecting a DropDownList is a client side event. So, you need to pass to the server the value selected, and return the HTML for the "rows" part. To do this, in Javascript you need to bind the onChange event for the DropDownList to get the selected value. Then... you do an AJAX request to the server "asking for the rows" and passing the row number.

ALSO, you could do it all in client side... generating the rows in client side... but in that case I suspect you will be in problems (not impossible, but tricky) at the moment of posting the user input in those rows to the server.

Your HTML:

```
    <table id="dynamiccount">
        <tr> 
            <td>
                <div class="editor-label">
                            @Html.Label("please select count")
                    </div>
                </td> 
                <td>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.count,(SelectList)ViewBag.dynamic,"select")
                            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.count)
                    </div>

                </td>
        </tr>
    </table>

<div id="placeholderForTable">

<div>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$( "#select" ).change(function() {
   var countSelected = $(this).val();

   $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'UrlToAction', //this Action need to return a PartialView
    data: "count=" + countSelected ,
    success: function(data){
        alert('successful');
        $('#placeholderForTable').html(data); //the HTML of the view is placed in the Div whose id is "placeHolderForTable"
    }
});
});
```

**The Controller Action:**

This is left to you to code :)

**Disclaimer:** all code was written here, no tested.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Please revisit updated code and revert.